# TextField currency format doesn't work when in ObservedObject

Tags: swiftui

When I have multiple textFields in a ForEach and use a viewModel the text works weirdly. This is test code:

```
struct TestItem: Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var value: Decimal?
}
```

```
class TestVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [TestItem(name: "arry"), TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0),
                            TestItem(name: "hehe", value: 21.0)
                            
                            
    ]
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TestVM()
    
    @State var num = Decimal()
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVStack{
                ForEach($vm.items, id: \.self){$val in
              
                        HStack{
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                            }
                            
                            TextField("Value", value: $val.value, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                                .id(val.id)
                                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        
                                .frame(maxWidth: 85)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that if you type in the textField and start deleting the 21.0 value that when you delete the 1 it'll round to $2.00. If you add a new number, it'll round automatically. The textField loses focus each time.

However, if you just use a State variable it works fine:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TestVM()

    @State var num: Decimal = 27.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }

                TextField("Value", value: $num, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

                    .frame(maxWidth: 85)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for your `TestItem`

Comment: Please add your images properly using the insert image functionality on the toolbar. SO requires that all images used here be uploaded to their Imgur account so that they remain available for future site users. Links to images hosted elsewhere are not allowed.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine added

Comment: @KenWhite yeah my bad. I was trying to link a gif, but I deleted the links instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by making `TestItem` conform to `Identifiable`:

```swift
struct TestItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String;
    var value: Double?;
    let id = UUID();
}
```

And then updating the ForEach like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TestVM()
    @State var num = Decimal()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                ForEach($vm.items){$val in
                    HStack{
                        Button {
                                
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        }
                            
                        TextField("Value", value: $val.value, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                            .id(val.id)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 85)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something with using `.\self` in ForEach when updating the textfield causes it to lose focus. Giving each `TestItem` its own `id` resolves this.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you are using

```
ForEach($vm.items, id: \.self)
```

This means that `ForEach` will use the items themselves to identify its children. If an item changes so that it is no longer equal (by `==`) to what it was before, then `ForEach` redraws that particular child.

Because you used the automatically generated implementation of `Hashable`/`Equatable`, your `TestItem`s' `==` also take into account the `value` property. If the `value`s of two `TestItem`s are not equal, then the two `TestItem`s are considered not equal by `==`.

As a result, when you change the `value` to something else using the `TextField`, the `ForEach` thinks that a new `TestItem` replaced the existing one, because the `TestItem` after your change is not equal to the `TestItem` before your change. This causes the `ForEach` to recreate the `TextField`, and this causes it to lose focus. There is literally a new text field, and the one you were focusing on was gone.

You should use the `id` property as the `id:` parameter. This can never change.

```
ForEach($vm.items, id: \.id)
```

Alternatively, conform `TestItem` to `Identifiable`, so you don't even need an `id:` parameter

```
extension TestItem: Identifiable {}
```

```
ForEach($vm.items)
```